# Getting lots of entries in delta API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php, chdropboxsync

I have an app where i am using delta API to keep up with user's metadata 
changes. I have a user for whom i am getting a lot of entries and cursor 
is keep on changing. It has been 2 days and still i am keep on getting 
new cursor, which has "has_more" as true. I have so far processed 
about 400,000 entries and only 17,000 entries were entries with 
metadata, all others were delete entries.

Is this a normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You should go to https://www.dropbox.com/developers and click on `API Support` to report this issue. It seems like this should be optimized.